# iTerm tab takes about 30s to load

Tags: iterm2, iterm

This has been an issue going on for a while and I've tried several solutions over the past several months. Since I have my tabs open most of the time, I was able to live with it for a while but I want to understand what's going on.

Here are some of the things I've tried already.

1. Deleting the ASL files. This is something I saw in multiple places so I run `rm -rf /var/log/asl/*.asl` frequently but hasn't helped much.
2. I changed my terminal launch command to be `/bin/bash -il` as it should bypass the login performance issue but still no help.

Recently I've also started experiencing another thing when opening a new tab:

```
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
bash: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

Basically I need some help understanding what might be causing the issues and resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change your open file limit. [This](https://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/using/performance/open-files-limit/#mac-os-x-el-capitan) article contains useful information about open files limit and covers different operating systems.